# Let $\alpha: V\to V$ be the linear transformation given by $\alpha: p(x)\to p(x+1)-p(x).$ Find $ker(\alpha)$ and $im(\alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let V be the subspace of $\mathbb R[x]$ composed of all polynomials of degree at most $n$. Let $\alpha: V\to V$ be the linear transformation given by $\alpha: p(x)\to p(x+1)-p(x).$ Find $ker(\alpha)$ and $im(\alpha)$.

I am not sure where to start with this so if someone could give me a hint that would be cool.

Comment: Look at what happens to the basis elements and extend by linearity. You have the basis $1, x, \ldots, x^n$. Hence for example $\alpha(1)=0$, so $$\Bbb R\subseteq \ker(\alpha)$

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens for small $n$?

Comment: You can observe that if $p$ has degree $k$ then $p(x+1) - p(x)$ has degree $k-1$ (or $-\infty$ if $p$ is constant).

Comment: Start from basic definitions: the kernel of a linear transformation is the set of vectors (in this case polynomials) that are mapped to zero. So, you’re looking for polynomials that satisfy $p(x)=p(x+1)$ for all $x$. How does this condition restrict the degree and coefficients of a polynomial?